# Why subl.exe won't open new file unless Sublime Text is already running?

Tags: cmd, sublimetext3

I've followed [this tutorial on how to add Sublime Text into Windows cmd](https://scotch.io/amp/tutorials/open-sublime-text-from-the-command-line-using-subl-exe-windows) and after adding it to the PATH, I couldn't open a new file using `$ subl.exe filename` unless Sublime Text is already running, please help! Thanks

Comment: It should start Sublime if it's not running already. Do you see any error messages?

Comment: No, there's no error!

Comment: If running `subl.exe` doesn't make Windows complain (i.e. it's definitly running it), then the only thing I can think of is that if you're using multiple desktops it might be running on another desktop and not promoting the new window to the current one or something.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `subl.exe -n filename` (`-n` makes it open a new window) behave any differently?

Comment: I'm only running one desktop. It's weird!